# GET vs POST file download using express.js - changing the REST verb results in larger and incorrect file

Tags: javascript, rest, express, post

My situation is that in one of my services I provide many REST GET APIs to allow the downloading of files (typically xlsx).

In a new API I have a POST API which does exactly the same thing as another GET API (I've copied pasted the code line by line), except that it's using a POST instead of a GET

```
export async function postDownloadMyFile (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
): Promise<Response> {

  ... // xlsx workBook creation code
  const buffer =  await workBook.xlsx.writeBuffer();

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 'MyFile.xlsx');
  res.write(buffer, 'binary');
  res.end();

  return res;
}
```

but when the frontend client makes a request to download the file, the file comes back about twice the size than if I used a GET request and cannot be opened (presumably wrong format/buffer written out wrong).

changing the frontend and backend to use a GET (not modifying the body of the function above) 'fixes' the issue.

Are there some additional headers I'm meant to be setting?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try writing the buffer to disk and compare the files? I doubt the GET vs POST transfer is the problem, more about the part of code you omitted.

Comment: I don't have a solution to your problem, but if I was in your position, in order to debug it I would check the request and response headers of the GET and POST and check if anything is missing in the POST

Comment: Can you share how the workbook creation code accesses the `req` object? I mean, the contents of the workbook surely depend on the request being sent, for example, on `req.query` or `req.body`.